# How to get contract data?

Tags: etherscan, python, explorer-api

Let's say we have information about [WePower contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0x4CF488387F035FF08c371515562CBa712f9015d4#readContract).

I would like get some information about this contract via API. For eg. this,

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0x4CF488387F035FF08c371515562CBa712f9015d4&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

But there are no values of parameters -- only it's description(contract ABI ).
Is there are any methods to get it?

Comment: your question is bit unclear to me, what do exactly want to know? Aren't you getting a response from etherscan or what?

Comment: I want to get value of 'paused' parameter via api. thank you for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are here, from the API call with the query param `action=getabi`, requesting the ABI of the contract. So it supposed to return the ABI but nothing else, as you have correctly gotten.

Since you need to read a value of a variable in the contract using query param `action=eth_call` might do this. Refer [this discussion](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/6916/reading-contract-constants-via-api) here as well.

**UPDATE:**

I think, I got it working. I haven't dealt much with etherscan API. But I think this is what you are looking for.

As per the discussion above mentioned, you first need to get the Keccak-256 Hash value of `paused()` and get the sub-string of 8 characters and join `0x` to the front => `0x5c975abb`. Then query param `data` should set to that. i.e. `data=0x5c975abb`.

Then the API url should look like;

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=0x4CF488387F035FF08c371515562CBa712f9015d4&data=0x5c975abb&apikey=my-api-key=YourAPIKey
```

The response I got looked;

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
}
```

The `result` should be the value of paused which is 1 means `true`.

Comment: can't read using query param `action=eth_call`. should install ethereum client?

Comment: nope, it seems just an api call would do. I think I got it working let me update the answer

Answer (score 3):

As @AchalaDissanayake have correctly mentioned, You are requesting the ABI from the Etherscan API. That's why you get the description.

You should alter the API url to get internal data from the contract.